# VSIX document.Close() cannot be called within an event handler

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

I'm writing a VSIX extension that reacts to file being opened in Visual Studio.

```
  private DocumentEvents _events;

  private DocumentOpenListener(DocumentEvents events)
  {
     _events = events;
     _events.DocumentOpened += DocumentOpened;
  }

  private void DocumentOpened(Document document)
  {
        //Stuff to do when a document is opened
  }
```

On some occasion, I want to change which document will be opened.

But I can't modify `document.Path` (which is read only) because `_events.DocumentOpened` is fired after the document as been loaded.

So I wanted to close the document that was just opened and open a new one.

- Later part is done with with `_DTE.ItemOperations.OpenFile(correctFilePath)`
- For the former I wanted to do `document.Close()` but I get a runtime error:

  `document.Close() cannot be called within an event handler`

Why is that, and how could I open "my/path/to/file.cs" instead of "some/path/to/file.cs" when the later is selected?

Comment: What will happen if you don't close it immediately? Let it queue up first, then delay it for a while, and then try to close it again.

Comment: That's the question, I don't know how to do that